# Setting subversion "password-stores" does nothing?

Tags: svn, ssl-certificate

The Subversion documentation says that I can set a parameter in `~/.subversion/config` like

```
[auths]
password-stores = gnome-keyring
```

to have it cache my certificate password in gnome-keyring.  I set the option, and nothing happens -- no error messages, no change in behavior, nothing.  Maybe I'm missing a log somewhere?

I know subversion has to be compiled to support this but AFAIK I'm using the RPM version, which (they say...) ships with it rolled in.  Is there a way to check whether my binary supports keyring?  Shouldn't it say *something* if it doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was running an older version of Subversion.  I don't have the minimum required version on hand, but update to latest if you're having this issue, and you should be good to go.